# Get EntityContainer name

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, edmx

Is there a way to get the EntityContainer name by an ObjectContext or by an EntityType?

I can get database name using:

```
var database = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).StoreConnection.Database;
```

But what I'm really looking for is the EntityContainer name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get all the containers :

```
ReadOnlyCollection<EntityContainer> containers = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).GetMetadataWorkspace().GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace);
```

You can see here [Get EntityContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.entitycontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)